# Causing SSH to Time Out (client side)

Tags: ssh

I have a little Raspberry Pi that I'm playing with.  I've got it running headless, and I need to make it forward one of its ports to a remote server when certain conditions are satisfied.

However, I don't want the connection to sit indefinitely until the server closes it.  **Is there a way to close an SSH connection** (from the client, I have no root to the server) **after a certain amount of time?**  Ideally I'd do it directly via the ssh command, but I'm writing in Python 3, so if there's a way to do this in Python, then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

In your /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
ClientAliveInterval <time interval in seconds>
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

So using 300 in the first directive will kick the connection after 5 minutes idle. You'll need to restart sshd to make it take effect.

Comment: Good idea but he says he has no access to the server.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I have no root to the server or this would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=10 server.org

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like it just sends a ping every once in a while to keep the connection open.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you run `ssh` with the "-N" option, it normally launches some kind of command or shell on the remote system (the Pi in this case). Ssh disconnects when this remote command exits.

If you're running ssh just to create some port forwards, you may be running with "-N", or you may be letting the ssh session sit at a command prompt. Instead, you could launch a command on the Pi which exits after the desired period of time. You could use the `sleep` command, for example:

```
ssh -Lwhatever -Rwhatever user@pi "sleep 3600"
```